# How to clean up an XML file for Java parsing by putting quotes around attributes

Tags: java, xml, regex, xml-parsing, jtidy

I have a series of xml files that looks something like this:

```
<ROOT>
    <F P=100> Some text here </F>
    <F P=101> More text </F>
    ...
</ROOT>
```

I'm trying to parse the xml using the standard DOM way, but because the attribute values for `P` are not in quotes, Java complains.

I tried using JTidy to clean it up, but because my xml isn't HTML, Tidy throws errors complaining that it doesn't recognize the tags `<ROOT>` and `<F>` etc.

So, is there another way to do this? Alternatively, I guess I could use regex since the only  attributes without quotes occur in the `<F>` tags. Any thoughts on either?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There has been a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964200/how-can-i-make-my-xml-safe-for-parsing-when-it-has-character-in-it) a few days ago. Your case is perhaps easy to handle with regex iff you have few tags and attributes to work with. Otherwise, I think the real solution is go back to the provider of those files and ask them to build valid XML.

Comment: Nvm, fixed it. All I had to do was set `tidy.setXmlTags(true)` so that tidy treats the input as XML and not HTML

Comment: Please don't call them XML files when they aren't, it's very confusing. Call them non-XML files, and then we'll all know what you are talking about. It also make it clear that you need non-XML tools to process them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> All I had to do was set tidy.setXmlTags(true) so that tidy treats the input as XML and not HTML

– sheldon

Comment: I know this comes very late. But do you happen to have the piece of jtidy code you use to tidy the XML. I have a very similar problem & jtidy does not work for me. Thanks so much

Comment: @Harish, this is a direct quote from the comments on the question above. You can try asking the poster there.